# Setting variables in global 'before' in mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Say I have the following directory hierarchy:

```
Project/  
  ActualProject.js  
  Test/  
    hooks.js  
    testsForFeature1.js  
    testsforFeature2.js
```

In hooks.js, I have a 'before' function. In this function, I do some setup, call a function on a server, and get an ID back. I want to take this ID and pass it to testsforFeature1.js and testsForFeature2.js. Is there a good way to do this?

I could always write the value to a file somewhere, and read that file in each test, but that does not seem like the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the environment variabls

`process.env.id=value`   **//to set environment variable**

and

`id=process.env.id`       **// to get that id in other files**